# date formatting issue when using to_char

Tags: ubuntu, psql

I am encountering issues with the date and time returned when formatting with to_char in my psql script.

## select version();

PostgreSQL 13.6 (Ubuntu 13.6-0ubuntu0.21.10.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2) 11.2.0, 64-bit

the psql script is below plus the output.

the first now() correctly returns the date and time

now I try to use the to_char to format the output but the time returned is incorrect.

I later use the to_char to format a timestamp from data in a table and this works correctly.

do I need to use the extract function instead? and also how can I suppress the carriage return on the previous echo statement.

Also when I direct the ouput to a file the echo statements are not present.

help appreciated.

\pset format unaligned
\pset fieldsep ','

! echo
! echo
! echo 'Report Name: XXX-23-001-v01'
! echo 'Report content: Reminders'

! echo
! echo 'report generated at: ';

select now();
select to_char(now(), 'DD-MM-YYYY  HH24:MM');

! echo
! echo

! echo 'data current as at: ';
select to_char(created_at, 'DD-MM-YYYY  HH24:MM')  from customer_events order by created_at DESC limit 1 ;

** OUTPUT ***

Output format is unaligned.
Field separator is ",".

Report Name: XXX-23-001-v01
Report content: Reminders
report generated at:
2023-09-11 07:28:21.716321+01
11-09-2023  07:09

data current as at:
08-09-2023  23:09

Comment: Probably just a typo. `MM` is the format for the month. If you want minutes, use `MI`.

Comment: MI worked so first issue resolved thank you.

Comment: can anyone help me with how to suppress a carriage return with the echo command I have checked the man pages but without joy?

Comment: That looks like a different question, and one that the `man` page for `echo` can easily answer.

Comment: found it cant believe i missed it -n thank you Laurenz